# How to get the x and y coordinates of a label in TKINTER?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a Tkinter form and have added a label on it and placed it at (x=10,y=15) using the following command:

```
label_0.place(x=10,y=15)
```

what I'd like to do is something like:

```
print(label_0.place)
```

expected output:

```
x=10,y=15
```

How can I print the coordinates? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `place_info` will return all of the information used by `place` for that widget.

```
>>> print(label_0.place_info())
{'in': <tkinter.Tk object .>, 'x': '10', 'relx': '0', 'y': '15', 'rely': '0', 'width': '', 'relwidth': '', 'height': '', 'relheight': '', 'anchor': 'nw', 'bordermode': 'inside'}
```

If you just want the x/y coordinate no matter how it was added to the window, you can use the `winfo_x()` and `winfo_y()` methods.